# Android NDK and dlopen which depends on other libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, load, shared-libraries

I'm trying to execute a simple C program directly on android.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *Mylib = dlopen("path/to/some/so/library", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!Mylib) {
            fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
            exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I build this sing NDK with Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_CFLAGS +=-fPIE 
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie 
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl 
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

But upon loading the lib I get this

> dlopen failed: library "libvendorconn.so" not found1|

So apparently the lib I'm trying to open needs an ohter library (libvendorconn.so no idea where it is) maybe a default android lib somewhere in the system ?

Is there a way to solve this? Pheraps instruct NDK when building to use the system lib if required ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `dlopen("libvendorconn.so", RTLD_NOW)` and the loader will try to find it in its default search path.

Old versions of Android had a loader that required you to load your libraries in a very specific order for it to work. In Java land the best way to solve this is to use [ReLinker](https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker), but that won't help you for a pure native binary. The NDK ships `ndk-depends` (apparently undocumented) that can help with this.